# MQTT Android 11 TLS - Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, tls1.2

I am using a self signed CA to establish secure communication between MQTT (Mosquitto Broker) and an Android application (SDK 30, Android 11). The error message I am getting back is:

```
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I have seen different articles related to this issue and tested a handful of different solutions with no success.

According to the android documentation:

"Unknown certificate authority
In this case, the SSLHandshakeException occurs because you have a CA that isn't trusted by the system. It could be because you have a certificate from a new CA that isn't yet trusted by Android or your app is running on an older version without the CA. More often a CA is unknown because it isn't a public CA, but a private one issued by an organization such as a government, corporation, or education institution for their own use.

Fortunately, you can teach your application to trust custom CAs by configuring your application's Network Security Config, without needing to modify the code inside your application."

src: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl

So I followed the example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas) and added "trust" for additional CA's

I modified my `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the application and created the `network_security_config.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/ca"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

So I have the `ca.pem` file in my raw folder that meets the qualifications described in the documentation:

```
a raw resource ID pointing to a file containing X.509 certificates. Certificates must be encoded in DER or PEM format. In the case of PEM certificates, the file must not contain extra non-PEM data such as comments.
```

I even added the CA to my emulated android device according to manually adding CA's via this article [here](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/android-11-trust-ca-certificates/) and the issue still hasn't been resolved.

Here is how I am setting up the 2 way TLS socket:

```java
private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(InputStream caCrtFile, InputStream crtFile, InputStream keyFile,
                                              String password) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // load CA certificate
        X509Certificate caCert = null;

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(caCrtFile);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
        }

        // load client certificate
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(crtFile);
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
        }

        // load client private cert
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new InputStreamReader(keyFile));
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
        KeyPair key = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);

        KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        caKs.load(null, null);
        caKs.setCertificateEntry("cert-certificate", caCert);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(caKs);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("certificate", cert);
        ks.setKeyEntry("private-cert", key.getPrivate(), password.toCharArray(),
                new java.security.cert.Certificate[]{cert});
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

Then passing in the raw files as socket options:

```java
 InputStream caCrtFile = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ca);
                InputStream crtFile = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
                InputStream keyFile = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key);
                options.setSocketFactory(getSocketFactory(caCrtFile, crtFile, keyFile, ""));
                connect(options);
```

articles referenced:

- https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/android-mqtt-ssl-tls-authentication
- https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl
- https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas
- https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/android-11-trust-ca-certificates/

Any insight would be appreciated and considered!